# Imported .svg files does not show up

Tags: import, file-format

I'm new to Blender and trying to make a 3D model out of a 2D image.
I made an inkscape 2D trace and saved as .svg file. When trying to import it to Blender, it does not show anything in the editor.

Any possible reasons you could help me with ?

Comment: please upload the blend file or the svg file.

Comment: [link]http://tinypic.com/r/2ebgv47/8 Here is the image. I'm unable to send you .svg file sorry.

Comment: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/777f0695115070a869ebaecc3782021e20140324175156/0f3a01aa564f86de4009775f08e519a920140324175156/29a7ee Finally SVG file here!

Comment: there seems to be a problem with the SVG file. A. it does not even look like a svg, it pixelates when I zoom in, not sure if that is just IE. Also the file does not show up because it does not even import succesfully, I have the same problem in PS.

Comment: I tried re-creating SVG. It gives same problem.

Comment: how are you creating it?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2727/599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found issues with SVG or illustrator when the shape is filled but is not a closed curve or when the shapes have overlapping lines or fills.
On the other hand, for such a simple shape you could import the image as background and trace it as a curve directly in blender.
[image]

Comment: Hi, I generally plan to work on various shapes. this is just one elementary shape. So, I need to know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: the svg does not contain the vectors of the image, just the raster data (Blender will not import those). You need to trace the image using the trace bitmap function in inkscape to have curves. Once you have your image as a series of vectorial curves save it as svg and your object will import correctly into blender

Comment: here's a modified (traced) svg and blend file: http://we.tl/sNGIhR9l6o

Comment: cegaton is right. Embedded raster graphics like your jpeg can not be traced by the svg importer. Just trace the image in inkscape so it gets converted to vector graphics.

Comment: Btw in inkscape its under the main menu -> path -> trace bitmap or press shift+alt+b

Comment: i do that but it still wont open and an error message appears.any HELP?

Comment: @tanelorn What error?

Comment: read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23171/1853