# Is Blender Compatible with Powerpoint?

Tags: export

1. Can 3D images from Blender (and their motion paths) be imported into powerpoint
2. Can 3D characters created in powerpoint '16 be revised using Blender and then reinserted into Powerpoint

Answer (score 2):

ActiveX controls exist for Powerpoint allowing you to put 3D objects into powerpoint -- see http://www.3dcompress.com/web/download.asp as example.  Using Adobe Illustrator and some back-and-forth, you could handle shapes as SVG thru AI-- [Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape) -- which can be edited, and you can export SVG from Blender and import into Powerpoint after converting it to an .emf, which I believe is the only cross-compatible way to do so... But I have only recently started using AI '16.

You can certainly create effects within Blender that can be inserted into PPT as video files, too. A lot of neat visual stuff can be accomplished with embedded AVIs.

You can also create a hyperlink within PPT to a 3D model on a service like Sketchfab if your goal is to show the model itself... but not in an editable way that can be shown containerized within PPT, and this requires an Internet connection to Sketchfab.

Finally, I believe you were able at least in the past to make a Blender game and insert it as a browser object in PPT -- see http://geta3d.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=15&Itemid=20. I have not done this... and the file is not actually "in" the PPT.... it is linked.

But as I understand your intent, I think the answer is mostly "no"... or "not seamlessly."

EDIT: VRML might offer some compatibility, too, for shapes: VRML 2.0 import/export is an add-on in user preferences.