# How to import .ai files to blender

Tags: import

I installed [this](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/AI_PDF_SVG) add-on and tried to import .ai files from illustrator. Unfortunately, the imported 2d vector graphics where all in grey plane object- even though the paths where there.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

If you save from illustrator (or Inkspace) into SVG format, then you can import your elements to blender using the built in SVG importer:

[image]

Just make sure that **all of your elements have been coverted to pahts**.

Please read this post:[Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape/23171#23171)

Comment: That's not the case. I tried that as well. The photo in the example probably does not have a fill; it's just a path. In my case, I wanted to import the path filled with the colour. Only the method bellow helped me. Thank you.

Comment: Can you upload your ai file and share the link?

Comment: Filled paths are supported.

Comment: Save as PDF from AI or wherever, open in Inkscape, save as SVG, import SVG into Blender.

Answer (score 0):

So, the thing I thought was to save it as .SVG and then import it... I exorted the graphics as .SVG and even though in inkscape the file was loading as it was, in blender it was again the same...

Long story short, **I solved it by changing the file from .ai to .svg though this site**: http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-svg

There are many similar sites, just lookup "ai to svg" in Google

Comment: You can also save to SVG directly from Adobe Illustrator if you have that app.

Comment: I know, but I don't have Illustrator installed; I just had the .ai files.

Comment: Be careful by using that kind of service.
Take your time, reading the terms and conditions. Not only that you may be get charged for using the service of online convertion, you probably give away your hard work for comercial use by foreign companies.