# Blender isnt letting me import any SVG files

Tags: svg

I'm very new to blender but I've recently watched hundreds of tutorials showing me how to import svg files.  It seems very easy, a simple 1, 2 step posseces but for some odd reason I'm having no luck getting it to work.  At first I thought maybe I'm not saving my file correctly so I when on google and seached SVG files formatted down to the t.  I still have NO LUCK at all even gettin one out of the 20 professional svg files to work.  I'm starting to think maybe blender file might be corrupted.  Is there anyone eles who has had this problem where they were unable to get a single SVG file to import into the program.  I would love to hear how I can resolve this issue so that I can enjoy making countless of projects I have in mind

Comment: If the SVGs contain raster graphics or text then they have to be converted to curves (paths) before you can import them to blender. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape/23171#23171

Comment: you're not detailing what happens when you try: an error? a message? nothing? imported but wrong shape? imported but "invisible"? Have you tried to import those svg to Inkscape, and then maybe try to import in blender the svg saved from inkscape?