# SVG Import from Inkscape

Tags: import, svg

I wrote some text in Inkscape using a font called ITC Franklin, then exported to SVG to be able to import it into Blender.

However, it seems the SVG doesn't create instructions for drawing the curves of the font. It just includes a reference to the font used so that whatever application using it is supposed to use that font.

Not sure how it works, but when importing into Blender, it doesn't show anything.

Comment: That's a question about Inkscape, not about Blender. Anyway - Inkscape menu - Path - Object to Path would be the answer. For all your following questions after importing into Blender, please make sure you read all the svg import questions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=blender+inkscape+svg+import).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about Inkscape.

Comment: Also why the extra steps and not just use the font inside Blender directly?

Comment: @metaphor_set this is about Blender AND its relation with Inkscape, It's not off-topic.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of [Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/23170/30849) *"Currently the Blender's SVG importer can only read paths (vectorial graphics). Raster and text information will not be imported"* The answer includes informations on the steps in inkscape.