# Problem in importing .svg files to blender

Tags: import, svg

I am aware that this looks like a repost (and it probably is) but I just cannot seem to fix my problem with the post I have found on the topic.

Here is my goal and the problem: 
I am trying to integrate a molecular structure into my 3D render. I am therefore following a tutorial I found on youtube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iC2Yvf1bIFA&t=433s). I am very simply drawing the molecule on ChemDraw, saving it as a PNG, opening it into Inkscape and using the "Trace to Bitmap" button. Then, I am saving my picture as an SVG.

Problem is, when I get to blender and import that SVG file, I do not obtain a curve (like the lady in the tutorial). Instead, I obtain a collection (see picture below), and I can zoom in all I want, I never start seeing my molecule.

[image]

Do you guys know anything about this? What I have tried is to download a PNG picture from google and turn it into a SVG, then importing it into blender. The same problem occured, however, which leads me to think that I am either doing something wrong in Inkscape and/or in Blender.

I apologize in advance if my problem and its solution are trivial, I am rather new to all this.

Thanks,

Cyprien

Comment: Hey there, may i ask if you could you share a picture of the svg you intend to use. The outliner does sadly not help much, as Blender always creates a collection if you import an svg, so it does not tell much about the problem. Since you said it also happens when using a different png converted to svg, maybe sharing the .blend file with the imported svg could clear up something. You can use [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), you will need to copy the address of the question in order to use Blend-Exchange.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried these things? They are the most basic things you'd want to do in InkScape prior to importing to Blender:

1. Convert all strokes/fonts into path objects.
2. Delete everything that's not part of your actual art, eg. invisible boxes and unnecessary layers.
3. Merge your path objects with boolean as much as possible.

Edit: A nice video on the subject, that explains some quirks you might run into: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ctwiT8LYjVQ

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer to my problem. For some reason, if I trace bitmap in Inkscape by right clicking the picture instead of hitting the hotkey, it works.

Problem solved!