# Having trouble importing SVG file into blender

Tags: rendering, import, svg

I am attempting to import an svg file into blender order to create a 3d model. The software recognizes the file but when I try to import I can only see the file name pop up on the right hand side but nothing actually shows up on the canvas. I tried zooming in and scaling the object but there simply doesnt seem to be anything to select. Also when I go and try to click "open file with blender" the software opens for a brief moment and then shuts down. I am using Inkscape but have tried other online converters all to the same result. Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: generally it is very very small, so try to scale it 100 or 1 000 times? But maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape