# Blender 2.83 Scale SVG not showing visual effect

Tags: svg

I am a newbie with Blender (Version 2.83) on Windows 10. I want to do one simple job: import a SVG file and scale it in Blender.
I downloaded a football image in SVG file format, its name is like: C:\Temp\Brzauca01.svg Now, I open Blender 2.83 and delete the default image, then I import the football SVG file, but I can't see it from Blender. So I tried the following to scale the SVG image.
I typed S, then 5 trying to make it as 5 times as its original size, but I can't see any visual effect.
You can see the Blender IDE after I imported SVG file and after I typed S, 5
By the way, another picture you can see that I can use InkScape 1.0 to show the Brzauca01.svg, it is a football image in SVG format.
Please advice what I should do to show the visual effect for scaling a SVG file.[Blender IDE show SVG file after scale](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqKMB.png)
[image: Football SVG file shown in InkScape 1.0]

Comment: Was the element converted to paths? Blender cannot import Raster Images in a SVG container.  Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23171/92768. If you don't want to deal with vector graphics then export the image as PNG from Inkscape and import it using the "Import Images as Plane" addon.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your advice, I found the SVG file is not correct, it came without path information.  So I found another one, now, it works.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator-or-inkscape)

Comment: Yes, but I can't find how to mark this question as answered. Please help and thanks!