# Filling in curve deforms the curve object

Tags: modeling

As said in title, part of the curve object I'm trying to fill in, gets deformed after being filled

[image]
[image]

File download: https://www.mediafire.com/file/qynzjxr4bxzs5h9/Hokkaido.blend/file

Comment: Check doubles (control points) or move a bit with them ... or check this https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23171/2214 ... when exported from illustrator using Presentation Atributes solved my issue.

Comment: @vklidu I tred moving control points and it unfortunally has made everything even messier - something is broken with that part and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Your curve is too much dense.

---

Switch curve type from *Poly* to **Bezier** (*3Dview Editor > Curve > Set Spline Type*).
Than search for **Decimate** (or go to *3Dview Editor > Curve > Clean Up > Decimate Curve*) ...

[image]

... and use Decimate 0.1

[image]

[image]