# Blender will not import my svg in version 2.73

Tags: import

Blender will not import my svg image. I'm using inkscape and I made sure to use plain svg.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site =) Please provide more information about your problem, preferably with some screenshots. What's happening when you try to import?

Answer (score 1):

The SVG format can contain three types of graphic objects: vector graphics, raster graphics (bitmap images), and text. Blender's SVG importer can **only deal with vectors (paths)**. So make sure you've traced your images as paths otherwise they will not load in Blender.
In Inkscape use main menu -> path -> trace bitmap or press shift+alt+b

Read: [Why can't I import a SVG file from Adobe Illustrator or Inkscape?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23170/why-cant-i-import-a-svg-file-from-adobe-illustrator) and [Imported .svg files does not show up](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/imported-svg-files-does-not-show-up) and [Why won't Blender let me import .svg files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23105/why-wont-blender-let-me-import-svg-files)

Comment: I figured out how to trace the bit map and get it into blender. But thanks for answering.