# SVG import not showing up,why?

Tags: bezier-curves, import, svg

I have a vector image that I want to animate in Blender. I imported the image from file but it does not show up on the Blender workspace. Do I have to tweak some settings in order for it to show up?

Comment: Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/imported-svg-files-does-not-show-up and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23105/why-wont-blender-let-me-import-svg-files

Answer (score 2):

Usually when you import a SVG file it is extremely small (so small you cant see it). Draw a box select ("B", or choose it from the outliner) around the center of your screen and scale it up by a lot (You still may not see anything, scale it up again) after scaling two or even three times you will start to see it.

After you get it to the size you want dont forget to apply the scale (CTRL+A) "apply scale"

Comment: I added a box using the "line" tool but it can't be selected or scaled up, how do you do that?

Comment: Im sorry I should of made that more clear. Erase that box you made. Just zoom out until you can see your entire grid and press "B" and draw the box select to cover the grid. Then hit "S"  and keep dragging to scale it up until you can see it. You might have to do this a few times.

Comment: @Chuck Houck It could be more efficient to use the [Outliner](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/outliner.html) for that to find out if that object was actually imported; search for its name in the list of the objects. Once found click on its name to make it active and then proceed to scaling / etc.

Comment: @MrZak Good point, edited my original post.