# Why won't logo display properly in solid mode?

Tags: bezier-curves

The curves look fine in wireframe, but in solid part of the "S" and about 1/4 of the bottom of the rounded square is missing (the first picture is wireframe and the second is solid).

[image: wireframe]

[image: solid]

Comment: Check your curves for any small gaps or intersections. These often throw off the fill operator, giving partially filled shapes..

Comment: it could also have been a problem with ortho mode, even though it wasn't, it's always nice to switch to a perspective to make sure there are no hidden faces or edges.

Comment: illustrated nicely here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/text-objects-are-messed-up-when-using-offset/2727#2727

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely cause is *Self Intersecting* segments. The same happens if you have a text object and extrude it to the point where Curves intersect other curves:

From: [text-objects-are-messed-up-when-using-offset/2727#2727](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2720/text-objects-are-messed-up-when-using-offset/2727#2727)  (Different question, same answer and reason)

[image: image or self intersection]