# How to add outline to text?

Tags: text-object

How would one add outline to a text object? Do text objects even have outline support?

Should I instead create the text in GIMP or a similar program and import them in blender to replace the text objects?

Comment: related: [Outline Bezier curve in 2D mode](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36862/outline-bezier-curve-in-2d-mode)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[image]

In the text font panel choose [none] as the fill type.

Notice the bevel value.

Combine two text objects for fill and outline.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If your text is in 2D, you can just convert it to mesh with Alt + C and then Inset some faces for outline with I. For 3D text i recommend [this short tutorial on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VHnENga-jZM)