# How to offset bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

I am not able to find offset bezier curve option in blender which is available in most of software
[image: offset curve]

Comment: You could do it this way but it's not completely satisfying if you want to keep curves (and not convert to mesh), so maybe there's another solution? Select your curve, go in the Properties panel > Geometry. Play with the Extrude value. Duplicate your curve with shift D and Enter. Play with the Offset value of your second curve.

Comment: Is it possible if i convert curves to mesh

Comment: yes you can convert curve to mesh with alt C

Comment: after alt c how to offset it

Comment: it looks like there was an addon (the Offset Tool) to do it but I can't find it, so I guess you only have indirect solutions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36862/outline-bezier-curve-in-2d-mode

Comment: After alt C, it's now a mesh, you extrude it on the Z axis, then alt S to offset it

Comment: Activate curve tools addon and use outline feature.

Answer (score 1):

Someone will tell if I'm wrong but it looks like there's no easy way to do it. In [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36862/outline-bezier-curve-in-2d-mode) they talk about an Offset Tool but I don't find it.

You could do it this way, but at the end you will need to convert your curve to mesh:

- Select your curve, go in the *Properties* panel > *Geometry*.
- Play with the *Extrude* value.
- Duplicate your curve with <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Play with the *Offset* value of your second curve.
- Convert your curve to mesh with <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>.
- If you decide to come back to curve, again <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>. As you will have a lot of vertices you can use the *Simplify Curves* addon (play with the values on the bottom of the T panel).

You could also directly convert your curve to mesh, then extrude your mesh on the Z axis, and <kbd>alt</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> (shrink) the shape. Then convert back to curve if you need, and again, use the *Simplify Curves* addon if you want to limit the amount of vertices.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Blender 2.8 in *Edit Mode* *Curve > Transform > PushPull* does the offset of selected vertices. Just found accidentally.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 2D curve, and in Object Mode,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> duplicate it, and then set the Offset value in the duplicate.

Or, you can create a 3D curve, and in Edit Mode, select all vertices, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>90</kbd> twist it through 90 degrees, and set an Extrude value to the desired width.

Neither of these options actually offsets the curve; neither moves the curve's vertices. They both, in their own way, make an offset of the polygonal approximation to the curve, whose resolution is set in the curve's Preview U field. In order to get two *curves* parallel to one another, with their own control points, you would have to convert to mesh and back again.

If you try things like setting the pivot to 'Individual Origins', the Transform Orientation to 'Normal' and in Edit Mode, selecting all vertices and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> duplicating them along their local Y tangent, you can see where the problem is. Although this actually works quite well for cyclic closed curves if the vertices are set to 'Aligned', open curves go awry. At the very least, in a Bezier, the control points would need altering in another direction to keep the splines parallel, when the vertices are moved. So the problem is not simply one of interpolation, as it is with a mesh: it's one of parametric curve-fitting.

Is the application you illustrate actually doing that? Plenty of vector-based drawing applications do, by approxination.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/408457/outline-of-cubic-bezier-curve-stroke)  and other places, for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per answer provided by: @Robin Betts
Using Blender 3.2  :

1. Enable Curve Tools:  *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Add Curve: Curve Tools*
2. In *Object Mode*, Right click on selected curve to get context menu and select   *Offset Curve*

You can generate multiple "offset tool paths". I don't know an easy way to separate multiple paths, so I generated several offset paths 1 path at a time.